# Angular issue with ngTemplateOut - NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I have two Angular components. The child component has just a simple TemplateRef and in the parent component I am looping over the content children and want to output the template of the child component and in this case I get the issue NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked.

**Source of the parent component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['parent.component.scss'],
  imports: [
    NgForOf,
    NgTemplateOutlet,
    NgIf
  ],
  standalone: true
})
export class ParentComponent {

  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)
  public children!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

}
```

**Template of the parent component**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="children">
  <div *ngFor="let child of children">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child.template" />
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

**Source of the child component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: 'child.component.html',
  standalone: true
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @ViewChild(TemplateRef)
  public template?: TemplateRef<any>;

}
```

**Template of the parent component**

```
<ng-template>
  <ng-content />
</ng-template>
```

With this sample I am getting the NG0100: Expression has changed after it was checked exception and it marks this part of the template as the issue: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="child.template" />`.

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

The last possible idea I got was that the issue comes from the `<ng-content />` inside the child components template and I tried to replace it with some dummy content, but even this was not the place of issue.

Comment: Hi, could you please provide a reproduced example on https://stackblitz.com/?

Answer (score 1):

`ChangeDetectionStrategy` : **OnPush** : It will enable manual change detection.

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['parent.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [
    NgForOf,
    NgTemplateOutlet,
    NgIf
  ],
  standalone: true
})
export class ParentComponent {

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)
  public children!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;
  
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
     this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: `AfterContentInit` lifecycle hook did not solve the issue, but I used your idea and call the ChangeDetector` now in the `AfterContentChecked` lifecycle hook.

Comment: @Gregor updated my answer with ngAfterContentChecked

Answer (score 0):

You can add a flag to initialize, when the content is initialized, using the `ngAfterContentInit` hook, this will ensure that the content is ready before it gets rendered, also we need to wrap it inside a `setTimeout`, to ensure the content has fully loaded.

parent

```
import { NgForOf, NgIf, NgTemplateOutlet } from '@angular/common';
import {
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  ContentChildren,
  QueryList,
} from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgForOf, NgTemplateOutlet, NgIf],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="contentVisible">
      <div *ngFor="let child of children">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="$any(child.template)" />
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  contentVisible = false;
  @ContentChildren(ChildComponent)
  public children!: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.contentVisible = true;
    });
  }
}
```

child

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <ng-template>
      <ng-content />
    </ng-template>
  `,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TemplateRef)
  public template?: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-iysyzm?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html,src%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)